# How can I get the raw curl request from an existing PHP curl handle

Tags: php, curl

For example, I have a PHP handle that has been initialized somewhere.

```php
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
```

And at one point I want to know the executed raw curl request

```php
curl_exec($ch);

// ???
some_method_to_get_raw_curl_request($ch);
```

Are there any built in methods that can be used for this? I tried looking in the [PHP Curl Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) but can't seem to find any. If there is none, are there any other way to do this?

Comment: Describe what you mean by "raw curl request"...

Comment: Postman refer to it as "raw text" when you try to import. The one that looks like this: `curl --location --request POST ...`

Comment: There is no built-in PHP function that returns the CURL command that could be ran on a command-line.

Comment: But can it be reconstructed from the `curl_getinfo()` details?